# How to mass delete everything in line after a certain amount of words?

Tags: notepad++

Example:

twenty four sixty eight nine

eight nine twenty four

sixty one fifty ten hundred one

to turn into:

twenty four sixty

eight nine twenty

sixty one fifty

I'm assuming the spaces will separate everything, but I got no clue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If words are, for you, any combination of non space character, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((?:\S+\s){3}).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: This works!! Thank you, I have scavenged the web and couldn't find any assistance except for you my legendary pal